# How to send Bluetooth data to an unknown device?

Tags: android, testing, bluetooth, hardware

I'm asking because I've been facing that issue for weeks.

I need to develop an Android application that can be able to perform an Bluetooth Connection and send data to an Bluetooth Hardware.

Ok, so here's the point:

is it possible to perform a RFCOMM connection to an 'unknown' device?
I mean, is it possible to do this without having any information about the hardware code?

Because i'm only able to modify the AndroidDevice (cellphone) code, for **SENDING** purposes.

I want to send a byte and make sure it was received, but there's only a sending code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could we have some more details? Is the other device accessible by you, as in can the other device know information about the Android device? And what do you mean by a "sending code"?

The Android device can pick up any active Bluetooth device in its range, and know the name and address of those devices. So, if the Android device doesn't know anything about the Bluetooth device it wants to connect to, you can always sort through the list of devices in range, and get its hardware code through that.

See the documentation about Bluetooth, specifically the Finding Devices section:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

I've done a fair amount of Bluetooth work with Android devices and Arduinos, and the Bluetooth library might be a bit of a pain to work with, but it is powerful.

Comment: I have the following situation:

1 - Android Phone
2 - Bluetooth Microcontroller Adapter (wich i dont know how it works, you just turn it on and it bond and connect devices by it's own)

I wanna send a byte from the Android Phone to the BluetoothAdapter, but i'm not sure if this is possible without the ReceiverCode, wich i dont have access.

Comment: What do you mean by ReceiverCode? Do you mean the address of the Bluetooth adapter, or the PIN for it?

Comment: No.
The Bluetooth powered device needs to listen while the AndroidPhone is sending. Got that?
Is there any way to make a secure connection having access only to the AndroidPhone code?

Comment: I don't think so. Bluetooth involves two devices that "agree" to connect to each other, it's not a broadcast protocol, meaning that the Android device can't just put data out to the world and hope someone's listening. For the Bluetooth APIs to work on the Android side, the Android device needs to be connected to the Bluetooth device, and for that you need information about the Bluetooth device. Otherwise, you won't be able to get an open stream to write data to.

Comment: Hmmm that's what i tought.
So now I need to check if the Bluetooth MC Adapter has an specific protocol to listen to incoming connections. Otherwise there's no way to perform a data transfer between those devices.
Thank you so much for the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

With bluetooth the two devices have a UUID. If you a writing a program that runs on both devices you have them listen for that UUID. When they connect as a client or a server you have a dataInputStream and a dataOutputStream. Then you can push and pull bytes out of those.